# I am developing an android CHAT app using firebase as its server for database support. Is this format right ? If not how would i alter it?

Tags: android, firebase, events, firebase-realtime-database, chat

The app is a group messaging and polling app. 
The following is my JSON tree. Please let me know if it is the right format. As to make a complex app easily read and write data.
I will be using android studio for the client side and will make push and put requests and want to iterate and read data ideally using a childEventAdded listner.

```
 {
      "Groups": {
        "0": {
          "name": "group1",
          "members": {
            "harsh": "true",
            "akshay": "true",
            "ninad": "true"
          }
        },
        "1": {
          "name": "friends",
          "members": {
            "harsh": "true",
            "akshay": "true"
          }
        }
      },

      "Members": {
        "0": {
          "member": "akshay",
          "phone": "8975629079",
          "groups": {
            "group1": "true",
            "friends": "true"
          }
        },
        "1": {
          "member": "harsh",
          "phone": "9986768678",
          "groups": {
            "group1": "true",
            "friends": "true",
            "new group": "true"
          }
        },
        "2": {
          "member": "ninad",
          "phone": "8172669079",
          "groups": {
            "group1": "true",
            "friends": "true"
          }
        }
      },

      "Messages": 
      {
            "0" : {
            "user": "997637364",
            "date": "24-6-2017:13:30",
            "messsagetxt": [ "hello", "how is everyone"],
            "group id" : "new group"
            },
            "1": {
            "user": "7768914250",
            "date": "24-6-2017:13:35",
            "messsagetxt": [ "hi "],
            "group id" : "new group"
          },
          "2" : {
            "user": "8808957364",
            "date": "24-6-2017:13:40",
            "messsagetxt": [ "thanks for adding", "how is everyone"],
            "group id" : "friends"
          }
          },

      "Events": {
        "polls": {
          "0": {
            "pollName": "Which movie",
            "date": "24-6-2017",
            "location": "Esquare",
            "pollans": {
              "hindi": {
                "8975629079": "true",
                "9923101446": "true"
              },
              "Eng": {
                "7736354748": "true",
                "7789384958": "true"
              }
            }
          },
          "1": {
            "pollName": "Which phone should i buy",
            "date": "4-2-2017",
            "location": "",
            "pollans": {
              "Samsung galaxy s8": {
                "8975629079": "true",
                "9923101446": "true",
                "7784650192": "True"
              },
              "iPhone 7+": {
                "7736354748": "true",
                "7789384958": "true"
            },
            "Windows Lumia": {
              "7736354748": "true"
            }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: its right if it works. lol. does it work?

Comment: This question had variable answers,
It depends on the pattern which can make the get and post requests the easiest that works.